# Jensen's Formula for Arbitrary Neighborhoods

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

The Jensen's formula says the following: Let $f$ be analytic  on the disc $D$ of radius $R$ centered at the origin  such that $f(0)\neq 0$,  then
\begin{align}
\log(|f(0)|)+ \sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(\frac{R}{a_i} \right ) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log(|f(Re^{i\theta})|)d\theta,
\end{align}
where $a_i$'s are zerof of $f$ in $D$.

Are there extensions of this theorem to regions other than discs.  For example, does it hold of rectangular regions?

Comment: I suppose a good start is with precomposing with some conformal maps of your choice to see how the formula changes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. See Theorem 3.13 in

Hayman, W. K.; Kennedy, P. B.
Subharmonic functions. Vol. I. (English)  [Zbl 0419.31001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0419.31001)
London Mathematical Society Monographs. No. 9. London-New York-San Francisco: Academic Press, a subsidiary of Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, Publishers, XVII, 284 p. (1976).
MSC:  31-02 31A05 31A15 31B05 31B15 31D05
(see the second page of  [the review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0419.31001) for its formulation).